# Java regular expression matches too much

Tags: java, regex, parsing

So I am writing a chess [PGN](http://www6.chessclub.com/help/PGN-spec) parser, and I'm having trouble breaking up the file.  Here are a few caveats:

I am slurping the entire file into a String, so what I have looks like:

```
[Event "Rising Stars vs Experience"]
[Site "Amsterdam NED"]
[Date "2010.08.22"]
[Round "10"]
[White "Peter Heine Nielsen"]
[Black "Anish Giri"]
[Result "1-0"]
[ECO "E05"]
[WhiteElo "2700"]
[BlackElo "2672"]
[Annotator "Soltis, Andy"]
[PlyCount "113"]
[EventDate "2010.08.12"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nf3 d5 4. g3 Be7 5. Bg2 O-O 6. O-O dxc4 7. Qc2 a6 8. a4
Bd7 9. Qxc4 Bc6 10. Bg5 h6 11. Bxf6 Bxf6 12. Nc3 Bxf3 13. Bxf3 c6 14. Qb3 Ra7
15. Ne4 Bxd4 16. Rfd1 Qb6 17. Qd3 c5 18. e3 Be5 19. Rac1 Nc6 20. Nxc5 Rd8 21.
Nd7 Qxb2 22. Qc4 b5 23. axb5 axb5 24. Qxc6 Raxd7 {Diagram [#]} 25. Qxd7 (25.
Rxd7 Rxd7 26. Qxd7 Qxc1+) 25... Rxd7 26. Rc8+ (26. Rxd7 Qxc1+) 26... Kh7 27.
Rxd7 Kg6 28. h4 Qa3 29. Kg2 Kf6 30. Rb7 Qd6 31. Ra8 b4 32. Raa7 Qf8 33. h5 Bd6
34. Rd7 Be5 35. Rab7 Qe8 36. Bd1 Bc3 37. Bb3 Bd2 38. Kf1 Bc3 39. Ke2 Qg8 40.
Bc2 Qe8 41. f4 g5 42. hxg6 fxg6 43. e4 g5 44. e5+ Bxe5 45. Rf7+ Qxf7 46. fxe5+
Kg7 47. Rxf7+ Kxf7 48. g4 Kg7 49. Kf3 Kf7 50. Bb3 Ke7 51. Ke4 Kf7 52. Bd1 Kg7
53. Kd4 Kg6 54. Kc4 h5 55. gxh5+ Kf5 56. h6 Kg6 57. Bg4 1-0
.
.
```

over and over again.  I'm trying to create a pattern that will parse out the tags in the beginning, and the move text afterwards.  So in the example I listed above, there should be 13 tags followed by 1 game text matched for this first game.  Each subsequent game is matched similarly.

The regular expression I'm using is:

```
private static final String PGN_PATTERN = "(^\\[\\w+\\s+\".*\"\\])+(.*(1-0|0-1))";
```

and I think the part that is messing me up is the `'.*'` expression I'm using the capture the game movements.  I haven't come up with a decent pattern yet for this part, so I just want to capture the game movements in a String and move on to the next pattern.

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: why use regex for the whole lot then?

Comment: i went down this path because i thought the code would be easier - feel free to correct me

Comment: You specify the logic above.  `there should be 13 tags followed by 1 game text`  - personally I would follow this logic

Comment: 13 tags are not required.  This particular game has 13 tags in it.  Other games in the same file may have more or less.  Perhaps you can respond with an answer, and a regular expression that I can try out.

Comment: What is it actually matching?  Are all of the games in a single file?  If so, you probably just need to change your `.*`s to `.*?`s.  By default `*` is greedy and will match as much as it possibly can.  You could also use `(?:1-0|0-1)` to make that a non-capture group.

Comment: Will game moves be always in format `\d\.\w{2}`?

Comment: @PM77-1 of course not. First of all, there are usually two plies, second, there are check signs too, third: castlings. etc.

Comment: `24. Qxc6 Raxd7 {Diagram [#]}` and `25. Qxd7 (25.
Rxd7 Rxd7 26. Qxd7 Qxc1+) 25... Rxd7` for instance.

Comment: adam I think your answer will work let me test it.  Can you supply it as an answer with a reason and context?

Comment: Changing `.*` to `.*?` as suggested above should work.  The other approach is to change `.*` to `[^"]*` which will prevent it from consuming any quote marks.

Comment: @adamdc78 your suggestion works.  Do you want to post it as an answer so I an accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable matching newlines with the dot with `Pattern.compile(PGN_PATTERN, Pattern.DOTALL)`.

Anyway, regexes are not the best way to parse this.

> So in the example I listed above, there should be 13 tags followed by 1 game text matched for this first game.

But your regex will return only 3 groups: #1 will contain one tag (**a group can contain only one value**), #3 will contain score, and #2 will contain a lot of different things.

If you want just skip the tags, you need to fix your regex:

```
PGN_PATTERN = "(?:^\\[\\w+\\s+\"[^\"]*\"\\]\n+)+\n*(.*?(1-0|0-1))"; 
                ^                 ^         ^    |         ^
                |                 |         |    |         |
                |                 |         |    |         -- how do you match draws?
                |                 |         |    ---- blank lines between headers and body
                |                 |         --- you need to match the lines too
                |                 ---- so it won't match all the tags at once and will be faster
                ------- we're skipping them, so (?:…)
```

Now `group(1)` contains the moves with the score, `group(2)` the score itself, and headers are ignored.

To parse headers, you need something more complex, and not regexes.

Comment: I am ignoring draws right now - and I did indeed enable DOTALL.  +1